# What is the best way to slide/switch between views ? (Custom Launcher)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, slide, launcher, homescreen

I Build a Custom Launcher.

The launcher is made of views (each view will contain applications, images etc..)
The user can switch between those views in the home screen (almost like in every other laucncher)

the big difference is that in the launcher i build, when the user is in a specific view, he should be able to see the edges of the prev and/or the next view (if those are exist)

[image]

I tried to implement it by having a Horizontal Linear layout that holds the views.
It performs pretty nice, but not smooth enough.

I Concidered using viewflipper, but the problem with it, is that i can't see the prev and the next view.. (am i right?)

How should i implement this system?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ViewPager (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager). You need to download this .jar file to use it. http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Answer (score 0):

[`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) already does this.  It has issues with the smoothness and predictability of the left/right scrolling, but it will easily show your central view and the edges of the two neighboring views.

Comment: I'm switching a `Gallery` implementation to a `ViewPager` implementation today, but I'm not sure that `ViewPager` Aram suggests will show the borders of your neighboring views.